# JSON RPC in jqGrid

Tags: json, jqgrid, rpc

I am developing a web application which communicates to/from a server using JSON. I use

```
var jsonStr = '{ name: "Rob", time: "2pm" }';
jQuery("#name").jqGrid({
    type : "POST",
    url:'ControllerServlet?jsonData='+jsonStr,
    datatype: "json",
```

to pass data to server as JSON string, parse it in server, process it and send a JSON back which is displayed in the jqGrid.

This works for me, but I wonder what is the role of JSON-RPC; I read that it is used for remote calls. Is there any advantage in using JSON-RPC instead of using the above way to invoke servlet? How can I use JSON-RPC to do the same action?

Comment: The `url` which you use seems very strange especially for HTTP POST. If you use POST you should typically send all parameters in the body, like other jqGrid parameters `page`, `rows`, `sidx`, `sord`. You can just use `postData` parameter to do this. For example `postData: {name: "Rob", time: "2pm"}`. To send **all** parameters in JSON format to the server you can additionally use `serializeRowData: function (data) {return JSON.stringify(data);}` and optionally `ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" }` jqGrid parameter. You should change the server code after that.

Answer (score 0):

As the [website states](http://json-rpc.org/), JSON-RPC is a [remote procedure call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) protocol specification using JSON. It is therefore a specification to call remote methods/procedures on a server similar to [XML-RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC) or Java's [RMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_remote_method_invocation). Both JSON-RPC and XML-RPC can use HTTP as the underlying transport protocol but can also work with others.

On the other hand jqGrid and in general Ajax usually uses HTTP (ideally RESTful) requests to fetch or transfer direct representations of e.g. JSON or XML encoded data. By now this is the preferred way in JavaScript development ([comparison of REST vs XML-RPC](http://md314159265.wordpress.com/2006/10/30/comparison-of-rest-vs-xml-rpc/) is a nice read and applies to JSON-RPC as well).